# vba macro how to get alt text title reference/property

Tags: microsoft-word, vba

In VBA, how to I get a reference to the TITLE part of the alt text? It is not img.AlternativeText, that is the description. And img.Title gives "<Application-defined or object-defined error>" and I can't get or set it. If I try to get or set it, I get "run-time error 445: Object doesn't support this action", even though it shows up in the list of properties.

```
wdDoc.ActiveWindow.Document.InlineShapes(1).Title = "test"
```

[image]

**note** according to the official documentation here I should be able to edit this field:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.inlineshape.title

This is what shows up in VBA for the Title property:

[image]

code:

```
Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=doc, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
For Each sh In wdDoc.ActiveWindow.Document.InlineShapes 
    msgbox sh.Title
Next sh
```

This produces:

[image]

on the line where it's trying to show the title.

Comment: Your sample code with a for loop and the msgbox works fine for me, once I swap out your "FileName:=doc" with my "FileName:="C:\Temp\Doc1.docx". What version of Word are you using? Maybe it has an older version of the Common Controls, and that version is missing the Title property.

Comment: Word 2016 MSO 16.0.4849.1000 64-bit

Comment: Hmmm. That version should be fine. Is it possible that the particular picture/shape is somehow at fault? Do you get the same error if you start a new document and insert a new, different, picture?

Comment: I tried it with a new document and instead of dragging/dropping the image in, I used the Insert>picture and in that scenario it let me access the image title. What does that mean?

Comment: Dragging a picture in, I can reproduce your error. The picture I drug in ended up being a different type of object. It has "Format Text Effects" instead of "Format Picture". And right-clicking and choosing `Format Picture` brings up a different dialog. Whatever underlying object type it is, it still gets found as an InlineShape, but it doesn't have a Title property. It seems that not all InlineShapes are the same.

Comment: Is there a way to change the way the images are being embedded/inserted? Just to add, I have 197 documents that were generated by PHPWord, and each document has 6-7 images in it. The macro is trying to insert hyperlinks on each image (this works fine) and then set the title property to the hyperlink. I am trying to automate this process with the macro.

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/inserted-images-do-not-have-the-same-properties/a5ce2693-fb44-4a87-90b8-196954d246df and https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/different-menu-when-picture-drag-dropped-into/0d0b2b37-0bab-4896-8232-c7df89c4fa57?db=5&page=1 discuss this issue. A workaround is to save the document as a .doc format, then save it again back to .docx. That converts the "unusual" object to the kind you expect.

Comment: @DougDeden Thanks SO much for your help! I modified the macro to save the images with this and it fixed it! wdDoc.SaveAs2 FileName:=path & fname, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault, CompatibilityMode:=wdWord2013 If you add this as an answer I will check it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
'This displays the existing Alt Text Title.
MsgBox ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).Title
'So does this.
MsgBox ActiveWindow.Document.InlineShapes(1).Title

'This changes the Alt Text Title.
ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).Title = "New!"

'This displays the new Alt Text Title.
MsgBox ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1).Title
```

(Word 2013)

Comment: Do you know what would cause me to always get error 445 when I try that?

Comment: I don't know. I notice that you use a "wdDoc" reference, while my sample code does not. And, you use img.Title, while my sample code uses "...InlineShapes(1).Title". Perhaps you can reduce your code down to the simplest version that still exhibits the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for some suggestions.

Comment: I addded the code